# Query in MySQL to Find Distinct Status Based on Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My question is regarding a MySQL query that I am trying to write. I have written some psuedo-code to help illustrate what query I am trying to write:

```
SELECT *
FROM persons AS p
INNER JOIN person_info AS pi 
ON p.person_id = pi.person_id
WHERE status MAY INCLUDE lost, missing, or found
WHAT person_id has no instances of the found status
```

I'd like to know for each person_id (which can have multiple statuses), which do not have any instance of the status "found." I'm not concerned with just the records of lost and missing. I want to find the unique cases where there is no "found" status based on each unique, distinct person_id.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understand correctly, one option is to use `not in`:

```
select *
from persons
where personid not in (
    select personid
    from person_info
    where status = 'found'
)
```

This will return all records from the `persons` table that don't have a matching record in the `person_info` table with `status = 'found'`.

Alternatively you can use `left join/null check`.  `Not exists` can work, but may be slower with `mysql`.  There are some potential issues with `null` checks as well.  Depends on desired results at that point.

Comment: @Drew -- correct -- not in with null values can be a problem depending on desired results.  left join/null check might be preferred/optimal.  not exists might have performance impacts.  as usual, just depends...

Comment: trying to relocate an article I once stumbled upon about a team that spent 2 hours trying to figure out how `not in` did a bad transform ! Thanks.

Comment: @Drew -- here's a good posting comparing the methods.  In general, I actual prefer using exists, but mysql disagrees with me :)  http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: just posted an answer from where I left it months ago. It lacks nice accreditation for things like 3-prong. so just saying :(  So speaks more to 3-prong, than `Explain` optimization. When one knows their data not to be `null`, not an issue. But we are but mortals

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I took it @sgeddes. In writing it I realized it just makes peoples eyes glaze over.

SQL NOT IN () danger

```
create table mStatus
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    status varchar(10) not null
);
insert mStatus (status) values ('single'),('married'),('divorced'),('widow');

create table people
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    fullName varchar(100) not null,
    status varchar(10)  null
);
```

Chunk1:

```
truncate table people;
insert people (fullName,status) values ('John Henry','single');
select * from mstatus where status not in (select status from people);
```

** 3 rows, as expected **

Chunk2:

```
truncate table people;
insert people (fullName,status) values ('John Henry','single'),('Kim Billings',null);
select * from mstatus where status not in (select status from people);
```

**no rows, huh?**

Obviously this is 'incorrect'. It arises from SQL's use of three-valued logic, 
driven by the existence of NULL, a non-value indicating missing (or UNKNOWN) information. 
With NOT IN, Chunk2 it is translated like this:

```
status NOT IN ('married', 'divorced', 'widowed', NULL)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
NOT(status='single' OR status='married' OR status='widowed' OR status=NULL)
```

The expression "status=NULL" evaluates to UNKNOWN and, according to the rules of three-valued logic, 
NOT UNKNOWN also evaluates to UNKNOWN. As a result, all rows are filtered out and the query returns an empty set.

Possible solutions include:

```
select s.status
from mstatus s
left join people p
on p.status=s.status
where p.status is null
```

or use `not exists`

Comment: Very good explanation showing how `not in` can lead to undesired results when the field is nullable.

Comment: thx. Not meant to Answer question. Just sharing. I think SqlPolice invoked this investigation for me. Correction: I know he did. One of the benefits of peer review on the stack @sgeddes