# <> or NOT IN, and why does query return wrong results

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering about which is the better syntax between these two queries:

```
SELECT MyField1
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField2 <> 0 AND MyField2  <> 10
```

or:

```
SELECT MyField1
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField2 NOT IN (0, 10)
```

**EDIT**:

**Related question**: Why if I use `NOT IN (NULL, 0, 10)` I get no rows?

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: as long as whatever your query is ... it returns it the fastest and safest when  run thru `explain` wrapper, then whatever floats your boat. Safest would not include `NOT IN (null,0,10)` . Many of these queries are resolved to the same execution plan anyway.

Comment: @Drew If I use `NOT IN (NULL, 0, 10)` I get no rows! Instead using `NOT IN (0, 10)` NULL rows are excluded (honestly, I don't know why)

Comment: I was trying to point out the dangers of NOT IN when there is a null. I will forward on an interesting reference when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MyField2 NOT IN (0, 10)` is fine performance wise (the optimiser will be able to figure out the best approach) and expresses the intent the best (easy for humans to understand).

And why doesn't `MyField2 NOT IN (0, 10, NULL)` work?

In SQL, any equality comparison with `NULL` results in `NULL`, ie `x = NULL` results in `NULL`, which is neither `true` nor `false`. Since a `NOT IN (...)` requires comparison with every value in the list, the resulting list of (boolean) comparison results will contain a `NULL`. When determining if all comparisons are `false` (ie `AND`ing all the booleans together), the result is `NULL`, which is not `true`, so the test fails no matter what value is being tested.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `NOT IN` in general. Here is a [Don't Use Not In](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33405497) writeup I did a while back. *Don't use* unless you really know your data, and you really know how NOT IN morphs into ugliness.

In your very narrow question, and if you were a NOT IN expert, sure, NOT IN is the way to go.

Often the question is not (0,10) as in the op question. It is about should this be in my arsenal that I reach for often. And NOT IN is not one of them for me. It is very dangerous with null values, and as people often do not know their data, using that clause can waste precious hours.

Some day I will stumble back into a great blog someone wrote describing how he and 2 co-workers, all non slouchers, spent a decent amount of time scratching their head over why their NOT IN query was failing.

Comment: I read your rif-post and I thank you for giving these informations but it seems that both `MyField2 NOT IN (0, 10)` and `MyField2 <> 0 AND MyField2  <> 10` don't return rows with `NULL` value. So I don't see `NOT IN` more dangerous than `<>`

Comment: that is a different question then. Or in need of a clarification of what my data is, edit. I am giving things to think about. Note the verbiage in my link for `NOT EXISTS` clause

Answer (score 0):

Semantically both are equal. Potential performance differences should be the problem of the query optimizer. So it all boils down to which variant better states your intent.

Comment: I know that both queries give the same result. My question is: which one is to prefer (and why: faster; safest; and so on). I'll be grateful if you'll also answer to my update.

Comment: As I wrote, it depends on your intent.